# Google Analytics Goal tracking in javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a javascript/ajax based contact form on a website page. If people click to send the form, I want this click to be registered by Google Analytics. I created a goal for this, for some reason I cannot get it to work. Any help?

The code of the form is:

```
        <form id="footer_quick_contact_form" name="footer_quick_contact_form" class="quick-contact-form" action="includes/quickcontact.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="form_email" name="form_email" class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="E-mail">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="form_message" name="form_message" class="form-control" required placeholder="message" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="form_botcheck" name="form_botcheck" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-transparent text-gray btn-xs btn-flat mt-0" data-loading-text="One moment please...." onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'ContactRequest'});">Verstuur nu!</button>
          </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Quick Contact Form Validation-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $("#footer_quick_contact_form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              var form_btn = $(form).find('button[type="submit"]');
              var form_result_div = '#form-result';
              $(form_result_div).remove();
              form_btn.before('<div id="form-result" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;"></div>');
              var form_btn_old_msg = form_btn.html();
              form_btn.html(form_btn.prop('disabled', true).data("loading-text"));
              $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                dataType:  'json',
                success: function(data) {
                  if( data.status == 'true' ) {
                    $(form).find('.form-control').val('');
                  }
                  form_btn.prop('disabled', false).html(form_btn_old_msg);
                  $(form_result_div).html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                  setTimeout(function(){ $(form_result_div).fadeOut('slow') }, 6000);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        </script>
```

As you can see I added an on-click event to the send button. In google analytics I created a goal, by going to admin>goals>new goal>custom radio button>next. I gave the goal a name, selected the Event radio button and filled in the following fields:

Category: Contact
Action: ContactRequest
Label: Empty
Value: Empty

I thought I'd have fixed it, but until now I can't track any results in GA. Any suggestions?

Comment: How long is "until now" (data might take up to 24 hours to show up) ? Also, is your event not working or is it that your goal is not tracked (if you test goals remember that goals are counted only once per session, so if you want to trigger it multiple times in testing you'd have to use  incognito windows or delete your ga cookie between requests).

Comment: Hello Eike, thanks for you reaction. It's been more than 24 hours. I dont see the event in real time on Google Analytics, and I also don't see my filled in forms as conversion there... I'm not too familiar with programming in javascript, but is it possible that there needs to be some extra code to fire off the event to Google? If so, what would that be?

Comment: The GA code must be loaded, and it must be the proper version. Maybe you can include the GA snippet you use.

Comment: <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-98557943-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>

Answer (score 3):

After reading your comment it would seem the problem is that you are using the wrong syntax in your click event handler.

You are calling the ga() function, which is a part of the Universal Analytics Code, which for some time now has been replaced by gtag.js.

I do not usually use gtag.js (I prefer to use Google Tag Manager), but [according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#send_events) the correct call would look like this:

```
gtag('event', 'contact_request', { // second parameter is event action
  'event_category': 'contact', 
  'event_label': '',
  'value': 0
});
```

(Actually you can leave out label and value if you do not need them).