# Analytics - How to track clicks on a given button

Tags: google-analytics

I can't believe I have to ask for help for such a basic request, but it's driving me crazy :)

I need my Google Analytics reports to tell me how many times a given button has been clicked.

**I'm using the following code:**

index.html (`<head>` tag)

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456-1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-123456-1');
</script>
```

script.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ga('create', 'UA-130702382-1', 'auto', 'myButtonTracker');
});

myElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ga("myButtonTracker.send", "event", "button", "click", "myButton has been clicked.");
});
```

What on earth am I missing?

Comment: Same problem as this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747689/google-analytics-goal-tracking-in-javascript-ajax/53779379#53779379. ga() syntax is not compatible with gtag.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reforming with [gtag events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events).

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
'event_category': <category>,
'event_label': <label>,
'value': <value>
});
```